# How to set python indent offset to 2 spaces in elpy emacs?

Tags: python, indentation, elpy

I use `elpy` package for Python 3 in Emacs. It uses `yapf` to format a Python buffer. I have tried about everything, setting `tab-width` to 2 and setting `python-indent-offset` to 2 but nothing makes it so that when I run `elpy-format-code` the code is format using two spaces.

I have this in init file,

```lisp
(set-default tab-width 4)
```

But I also set it locally within my use-package declaration for elpy. Here are my elpy configs.

```lisp
;; elpy
(use-package elpy
  :ensure t 
  :init
  (elpy-enable)
  (setq python-shell-interpreter "python3"
        elpy-rpc-python-command "python3"
        python-shell-completion-native-enable nil
        elpy-shell-starting-directory 'current-directory
        python-remove-cwd-from-path nil
        ;; don't prompt before running compile
        compilation-read-command nil)
  ;; to keep the unhelpful warning from *Flymake log* buffer
  (remove-hook
   'flymake-diagnostic-functions
   'flymake-proc-legacy-flymake)
  :hook
  (elpy-mode . (lambda ()
                 (setq tab-width 2
                       python-indent-offset 2)
                 (highlight-indentation-mode -1))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `python-indent-guess-indent-offset` set to `t`? If so, then it's probably looking at your file and deciding to set the `python-indent-offset` to some other value. Try setting it to nil in the `:init` for the package. You could also check to see what the value of `python-indent-offset` is after you've opened the file using `C-h v python-indent-offset`.

Edit:

I just noticed that you're using an external tool called yapf to autoformat all your Python code. Are you sure it doesn't just defer all those decisions to yapf? Presumably yapf has a config file you are supposed to edit.

Comment: I tried `python-indent-guess-indent-offset` to nil and checked the `python-indent-offset` to be 2! The `yapf` formatting is still happening with 4 spaces.  There is also `python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose` which I did not change and is set to t.

Comment: It's actually not me who is using `yapf`, it came with the package `elpy`. Maybe you are right and I thought about that too but then thought `elpy` should parse the correct settings to `yapf`.

Comment: Reading [here](https://github.com/google/yapf#formatting-style), I was able to make a file `~/.config/yapf/style` and add `[style] \n INDENT_WIDTH=2` to it and then the `yapf` formatted the files with two spaces. If you add that to your answer, I'll accept it.